# Remove Columns from CSV File Using Powershell

Tags: csv, powershell

I need to remove several columns from a CSV file without importing the CSV file in Powershell. Below is an example of my input CSV and what I hope the output CSV can look like.

Input.csv

A,1,2,3,4,5

B,6,7,8,9,10

C,11,12,13,14,15

D,15,16,17,18,19,20

Idealoutput.csv

A,3,5

B,8,10

C,13,15

D,17,20

I have tried doing this the following code, but it is giving me plenty of errors and saying that I cannot use the "Delete" method this way (which I have done in the past)...Any ideas?

```
$Workbook1 = $Excel.Workbooks.open($file.FullName) 
$header = $Workbook1.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A68").EntireRow
$unneededcolumns1 = $Workbook1.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:O1").EntireColumn
$unneededcolumns2 = $Workbook1.ActiveSheet.Range("B1:K1").EntireColumn
$unneededcolumns3 = $Workbook1.ActiveSheet.Range("F1:I1").EntireColumn
$unneededcolumns4 = $Workbook1.ActiveSheet.Range("G1:I1").EntireColumn
$unneededcolumns5 = $Workbook1.ActiveSheet.Range("H1:O1").EntireColumn
$unneededcolumns6 = $Workbook1.ActiveSheet.Range("J1:AL1").EntireColumn
$unneededcolumns7 = $Workbook1.ActiveSheet.Range("K1").EntireColumn
$unneededcolumns8 = $Workbook1.ActiveSheet.Range("L1:AK1").EntireColumn
$unneededcolumns9 = $Workbook1.ActiveSheet.Range("F1:I1").EntireColumn
$unneededcolumns10 = $Workbook1.ActiveSheet.Range("M1:AB1").EntireColumn
$unneededcolumns11 = $Workbook1.ActiveSheet.Range("N1:X1").EntireColumn
$unneededcolumns12 = $Workbook1.ActiveSheet.Range("O1:BA1").EntireColumn
$unneededcolumns13 = $Workbook1.ActiveSheet.Range("P1:U1").EntireColumn
$header.Delete()
$unneededcolumns1.Delete()
$unneededcolumns2.Delete()
$unneededcolumns3.Delete()
$unneededcolumns4.Delete()
$unneededcolumns5.Delete()
$unneededcolumns6.Delete()
$unneededcolumns7.Delete()
$unneededcolumns8.Delete()
$unneededcolumns9.Delete()
$unneededcolumns10.Delete()
$unneededcolumns11.Delete()
$unneededcolumns12.Delete()
$unneededcolumns13.Delete()

$Workbook1.SaveAs("\\output.csv")
```

Comment: Why can't you import it in PowerShell? It would be __super__ easy to do this.

Comment: I'm not sure you're selecting the right Range(s) here... You do realize that `$Workbook1.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A68").EntireRow.Delete()` would effectively delete the contents in all cells on the first 68 first lines of your worksheet, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am just going to add this anyway since I hope to convince you how easy it will be to avoid having to use Excel.

```psh
$source = "c:\temp\file.csv"
$destination = "C:\temp\newfile.csv"
(Import-CSV $source -Header 1,2,3,4,5,6 | 
    Select "1","4","6" | 
    ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | 
    Select-Object -Skip 1) -replace '"' | Set-Content $destination
```

We assign arbitrary headers to the object and that way we can call the 1st, 4th and 6th columns by position. Once exported the file will have the following contents which match what I think you want and not what you had in the question. Your last line had an extra value (20) on it which I don't know if it was on purpose or not.

```psh
A,3,5
B,8,10
C,13,15
D,17,19
```

If this is not viable I am really interested as to why.

**Excel Approach**

Alright, so the file is enormous so Import-CSV is not a viable option. Keeping with your excel idea I came up with this. What it will do is take column indexes and delete any column that is not in those indices.

Wait you say?... that wont work since the column indexes change as you remove columns. Using the indices we want to keep we get the inverse to delete based on the `UsedRows` of the sheet. We then take each of those columns to delete and remove a value equal to is array position. Reason being is that when a column is actually deleted the next value has already been adjusted to account for the shift.

```psh
$file = "c:\temp\file.csv"
$ColumnsToKeep = 1,4,6

# Create the com object
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $False
$excel.visible = $False

# Open the CSV File
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($file)
$sheet = $workbook.Sheets.Item(1)

# Determine the number of rows in use
$maxColumns = $sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

$ColumnsToRemove = Compare-Object $ColumnsToKeep (1..$maxColumns) | Where-Object{$_.SideIndicator -eq "=>"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject
0..($ColumnsToRemove.Count - 1) | %{$ColumnsToRemove[$_] = $ColumnsToRemove[$_] - $_}
$ColumnsToRemove  | ForEach-Object{
    [void]$sheet.Cells.Item(1,$_).EntireColumn.Delete()
}

# Save the edited file
$workbook.SaveAs("C:\temp\newfile.csv", 6)

# Close excel and release the com object.
$workbook.Close($true)
$excel.Quit()
[void][System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
Remove-Variable excel
```

I was having issues with Excel remaining open even after reading up on the ["correct" way to do it](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730962.aspx). The inner logic is what is important. Don't forget to change your paths as needed.

Comment: I am sorry for not pointing it out in my original post. I cannot Import-CSV because the files are too large and Powershell takes a long a VERY long time to process each.

Comment: @CarlosSousa ah ok.... Still don't _need_ excel though. Can we assume the data does not contain commas? Also did you read Mathias' comment

Comment: @CarlosSousa I have updated the code to include an excel based solution. Try that out and let me know if it works.

Comment: thanks a lot. It does work. I am curious though, is there a better way to handle this? i.e. outside of Excel? a non-Excel based approach might be more efficient, correct? Any proposals?

Comment: You can use a streamreader or get-content with some switches with the combined logic of my first answer. Have a look at https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2007/06/17/optimizing-performance-of-get-content-for-large-files/

Answer (score 4):

Here's a better approach that I use, but it's not the most performant on large files. Both have been tested on 1GB files.

**Powershell:**

```
Import-Csv '.\inputfile.csv' 
  | select ColumnName1,ColumnName2,ColumnName3 
  | Export-Csv -Path .\outputfile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-5.1

If you want to get rid of those pesky quotes that the tool adds, upgrade to Powershell 7.

**Powershell 7+:**

```
Import-Csv '.\inputfile.csv' 
  | select ColumnName1,ColumnName2,ColumnName3 
  | Export-Csv -Path .\outputfile.csv -NoTypeInformation -UseQuotes Never
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7