# Parse existing CSV file and strip certain columns

Tags: powershell, csv, parsing

I have a CSV file which contains, let's say 50 different columns with 1000 rows. I don't need all of this information though and would like to now parse through it and remove the columns for which I do not want.

I want to keep every row (users) so I shouldn't be removing those wholesale, however, I have about a dozen or so columns for which I need to remove the data. How can I do this?

Ex.

```
User1 | Name | Age    | Location | Gender | HairColor
keep  | keep | remove | remove   | keep   | remove
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If so, post code.

Comment: Once `Import-Csv` pipe to `Select-Object` cmdlet you have the choice of either selecting the desired or choose all `*` and -Excludeproperty` the unwanted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Columns from CSV File Using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31325586/remove-columns-from-csv-file-using-powershell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the columns removed completely:

```
$CSV = Import-Csv $Path | Select-Object -Property User1, Name, Gender
$CSV | Export-Csv $NewPath -NoTypeInformation
```

Or this, if it's easier:

```
$CSV = Import-Csv $Path | Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty Age, Location, HairColor
$CSV | Export-Csv $NewPath -NoTypeInformation
```

If you want the columns to remain but be empty:

```
$CSV = Import-Csv $Path | Select-Object -Property User1, Name, @{n='Age';e={}}, @{n='Location';e={}}, Gender, @{n='HairColor';e={}}
$CSV | Export-Csv $NewPath -NoTypeInformation
```