# Remove Columns in multiple CSVs POWERSHELL

Tags: powershell

i have a folder like C:\temp with a lot of .csv files in it. All of these .csv files got the same structure without header. I need to delete the second and third column of each .csv file in this folder. How can i do this in powershell?

Comment: You can use the site search faility, to find some of the, _probably thousands_, of examples of scripts which are performing that task, and incorporate what you've learned from those into your own solution. Please also note, that there are no columns in a CSV file, there are records made up of `C`omma `S`eparated `V`alues, _(although other separators can be used too)_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove Columns from CSV File Using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31325586/remove-columns-from-csv-file-using-powershell). Please check: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: unfortunatly it doens't answer my question because i need to edit multiple csv at one time